# How can I send HTML email via Celery? It keeps sending in text/plain

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I setup a system Django/Celery/Redis. And I used EmailMultiAlternatives to send my HTML and Text email.

When I send email as part of the request process, the email is sent in HTML. All runs well and it wraps around a function. Here's the code:

```
def send_email(email, email_context={}, subject_template='', body_text_template='',
    body_html_template='', from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL):

    # render content
    subject = render_to_string([subject_template], context).replace('\n', ' ')
    body_text = render_to_string([body_text_template], context)
    body_html = render_to_string([body_html_template], context)

    # send email
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body_text, from_email, [email])
    email.attach_alternative(body_html, 'text/html')
    email.send()
```

However, when I tried to run it as a Celery Task, like below, it just sent as "text/plain". What could be the problem? Or what can I do to find out more? Any hint or solution are greatly appreciated.

```
@task(name='tasks.email_features', ignore_result=True)
def email_features(user):
    email.send_email(user.email,
        email_context={'user': user},
        subject_template='emails/features_subject.txt',
        body_text_template='emails/features_body.txt',
        body_html_template='emails/features_body.html')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Celery does not affect the executing results of tasks. Have you restarted celeryd after make change to the task? It's important for celery to reload the Python code.

When you were using `EmailMultiAlternatives` and `email.attach_alternative(body_html, 'text/html')`, the email was sent in the `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;` and the `text/html` is an alternative one, it depends on mail receipts to choose the content type of the mail during the rendering. So is the receipt same one between the view procedure and celery procedure?

You could output the sending mail directly, through `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25` to find out the actual messages. I've tested on my mac w/ redis-backed Celery, the outputs of the examples taken from [the official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs/#sending-alternative-content-types) are same as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from django.core import mail
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string
    from django.utils.html import strip_tags
    
    class SendEmail(Task):
        name="send_email"
        
        def run(self,email):
            subject = 'Daily News Letter'
            html_message = render_to_string('letter.html', {'context': 'values'})
            plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
            from_email = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER') 
            mail.send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [email], html_message=html_message)
            return None

send_email = celery_app.register_task(SendEmail())
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).